# How can I maintain and automate a list of download URLs with known hashes?

Tags: hash, integrity, debian

I'm familiar with the concept of downloading a file and manually checking it against a published checksum. See [How to verify the checksum of a downloaded file (pgp, sha, etc.)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189000) and [Is there a command line method by which I can check whether a downloaded file is complete or broken?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/135000) for examples.

I would now like to maintain my own list of target URLs and expected checksums, something like:

```
https://example.com/file.tar.gz, SHA123456...
https://example.org/list.txt, SHA1A1A1A...
```

...and automate the download-and-check process.

Before I make the mistake of hacking my own solution, is there an established way to do this on a Debian-based distro?

Comment: Hi David, this looks more a programing question from my point of view. You have your file with URLs and hashes and other process (python requests) downloads and check the file.

Comment: @camp0 That's actually exactly what I'm trying to avoid (programming a solution). Is there an existing tool for this? Or even better an existing strategy / file format? (so that this isn't a suggest-an-application question)

Comment: @camp0 Happy to take suggestions on how to word the question more clearly

Comment: please check this post https://superuser.com/questions/655346/wget-execute-script-after-download, the solution is really easy on bash and on python

Comment: Interesting question.  I cooked up a short python script to do this.  See https://pastebin.com/3iBHnT3q